# Is there any easy way to exclude a dependency in dev environment using composer?

Tags: composer-php

I'm using composer to manage a WordPress project and don't need some plugins in development. So basically the opposite of require-dev.

If there was a name for it I would guess it to be require-production or exclude-dev. So requirements in this object would only get installed if `composer --production` was ran. That's not a real flag, just trying to make the path to the solution clear.

```
"require-production": {
    "example/caching-plugin": "1.0"
}
```

**Is there a way to do this?**

I can do this with a php function, but would really like to keep my dependency management in one location

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, you can define [`replace` property](http://www.darwinbiler.com/how-does-the-replace-property-work-in-composer/) to specify list of packages to ignore, e.g.

```
{
    "require": {
        "example/caching-plugin": "*"
    },
    "replace": {
        "example/ignore-this": "*"
    }
}
```

This tells Composer that you're replacing these dependencies, so they won't be downloaded.

---

Another way is to perform code patching by adding this section:

```
"extra": {
  "patches": {
    "vendor/package": {
      "Bug #1234: Something is wrong": "patches/1234.diff"
    }
  }
}
```

For above feature to work, you need to install `cweagans/composer-patches` package first, e.g.

```
composer require "cweagans/composer-patches:~1.0"
```

Then you can provide different patch files on different branches for certain environments.

---

There is also `scripts` property where you can invoke some scripts or commands which can check your environment and depending on the hostname, can invoke certain commands to do some post-processing such as removing some files or folders.